# Codeigniter validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have many goals to be printed on the screen.
but it shows error when i use it like this

```
echo $this->validation->rshort_goal.$i;
```

What is the right way to use this?

```
if($sgoal !='')
{
    $scount = count($sgoal);
    $i =1;
    foreach($sgoal as $row)
    {
      <textarea name="rshort_goal<?php print $i;?>" id="short_goal" class="short_go">
      <?php if($this->validation->rshort_goal.$i)
                { 
                  echo $this->validation->rshort_goal.$i;
                }             
               elseif($this->validation->rshort_goal.$i._error !='') 
               { echo ''; } 
               else 
               {echo $$row->goal_description; }
           ?>
     </textarea>
        <?php
    $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo @$this->validation->{'rshort_goal'.$i};
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to call a function like this?

```
call_user_func($this->validation, 'rshort_goal' . $i);
```

Comment: Its not working. Because it will work if i put $this->validation->rshort_goal1. This 1 has to in a loop like 1,2,3

Comment: @Suj, I see what you're trying to do now.  Perhaps this helps?